# Applied for job now but will be able to work in the summer

Tags: professionalism, interviewing, communication

I have applied to several jobs for the summer, just regular ones like clothing retailers, etc. and I've gotten asked to come in for interviews this past week, but I go back to school this Saturday.

I won't be back until early May.  Is it a good idea to go through with the interview and tell them off the bat or get in contact with them beforehand to see what the options are?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I feel as long as you communicate that, you should be fine. Whether you do that before or during the interview is up to you. People may disagree with me, but I would argue it's the recruiters job to vet for these kinds of things and if this was a strong requirement, they would have mentioned it in the job posting.

You have already been accepted for the interview, so it would be good to go anyways and see what they are looking for then when they ask if you have any questions, you should bring up the situation you have and work things out from there.

Answer (score 0):

"When would you be able to start" is a fairly common interview question, especially towards the final interview - the employer wants to know if you have any notice period, travel plans, or contractual obligations that prevent you from starting immediately.

In your case, your desired start date is much later. I think the professional thing to do would be to bring it up yourself at the first opportunity - at the end of the interview when they ask "do you have any questions for us?" They probably already know that you are a student, so it will not be a huge shock.

To show that you are willing to be accommodating if they want to play ball, you could communicate your willingness to attend training for the position slightly earlier than your official start date (for instance, if your school is local, and you can come in on weekends or days during the exam period when you don't need to study).